# Why HTML selection returns random string?

Tags: php, html

I have a `<select>` form on my webpage containing 4 options with values from 1 to 4, when choosing an option the form should return one of the numbers but it returns 6 random characters instead.

The page does not contain any JavaScript and it is running on my local network, I've also disabled JavaScript on my browser.

The PHP i'm using to retrieve the value is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
    return $_POST[$key];
}
```

I removed any form of validation, i simply retrieve the value with `$_POST` and if set it prints out 6 random characters ( every time i submit the form ).

The form is the following:

```
<form action="/select_country" method="post" >
<select name="Country" class="country-selection">
    <option required="" selected="" disabled="" style="color: #b5b5be;">Country Location</option>
    <option value="1" >Asia</option>
    <option value="2" >Australia</option>
    <option value="3" >United States</option>
    <option value="4" >Europe</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Expected result: `1` or `2` or `3` or `4`

Actual result: `czWe8m` or `alBwKD` and so on...

EDIT:

The `$_GET` was a typo, sorry for that. Corrected.

I'm retrieving other input data from the same form using the same PHP code, the other tags are simple text and number `<input>` and they're working just fine:

```html
<input name="Title" type="text" placeholder="Insert Title" maxlength="100" required="">
```

```html
<input name="Description" style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="Insert Description" maxlength="1000" required="">
```

Comment: What is the value of `$key`?

Comment: Use $_POST. Because your form was method="post" otherwise you must change your method to "get" within the html form.

Comment: Why do you return a super global variable?

Comment: @Jeppe I am assuming that is $key = "Country"...

Comment: My bad sorry guys,  i couldn't find an explanation to the issue so i tried to retrieve that post data with a $_GET to see the results and i've pasted the wrong function here on StackOverflow. I've fixed the question by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has a select input and is set to use `POST`.
When it does submit the PHP will show you what was selected in the value
`$_POST["Country"]`

your first option is missing a value - so if that is submitted it may not show up as if they answered it. I suggest adding `value=""` so that it will be in the `POST` and you can validate that an option was chosen. Also, you need a submit button.

```
<form action="/select_country" method="post" >
<select name="Country" class="country-selection">
    <option value="" required="" selected="" disabled="" style="color: #b5b5be;">Country Location</option>
    <option value="1" >Asia</option>
    <option value="2" >Australia</option>
    <option value="3" >United States</option>
    <option value="4" >Europe</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and then:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["Country"]) {
    if ($_POST["Country"] == "") {
        // error you must select an option
    }
    //other validation here but this should be 1,2,3 or 4
    // keep in mind anyone can mess with the form and submit other things maliciously so do validate

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to be using `$_POST["Your Input item Name Here"]` because your form was using `POST` method and not `GET`.

Leaving your Html as is, please try the following:

```
//your name attribute = "Country" for select element
if (isset($_POST["Country"])) {
    return $_POST["Country"];
}
```

Comment: My bad sorry,  but i couldn't find an explanation to the issue so i tried to retrieve that post data with a $_GET to see the results and i've pasted the wrong function here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @chalky Awesome, you must always be aware of them. :)

Comment: Just finished to review some bits of code and it turns out i did the same mistake elsewhere. The worst thing is that it took me hours to find this dummy error! i was so desperate i decided to ask online lol. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Pleasure, That's why StackOverFlow exist, so don't feel stupid for asking; it only makes you better. Simple mistakes are often the ones daunting. :)

Comment: After fixing the typo the issue persisted. Sorry again. ::confused::

Comment: What is the value of $Key? Make sure $key = "Country"